# Strange behaviour using sudo with pipe

Tags: sudo, pipe

When I use sudo twice in two piped commands, I get the following output:

```
$ sudo echo 'hello world' | sudo cat
[sudo] password for zoey: [sudo] password for zoey:
```

And must enter my password twice. The first time, it is hidden as usual, but the second is shown in plaintext.

```
$ sudo echo 'hello world' | sudo cat
[sudo] password for zoey: [sudo] password for zoey: 
password123456seven
hello world
```

After the command exits, anything I type to the command line is hidden, as if I were typing a password, although command outputs work (mostly) fine. This behaviour continues until I close the terminal.

I tried:

```
$ echo 'hello world' | sudo cat
$ sudo echo 'hello world' | cat
```

And both seem to have normal behaviour.

I don't want to have to use `$ sudo bash -c "echo \'hello world\' | cat"`, which seems overly clunky, and would make quoted text a nightmare to handle.

Also, before anyone asks, yes, I know that `echo` and `cat` don't often require root permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this makes you feel better, but what you are observing doesn't occur in Ubuntu 16.04.  It does occur in Ubuntu 15.10 (which is what I presume you're using...or perhaps something older?).

Fortunately, I have a 16.04 and a 15.10 machine to try.  Under 16.04, I only have to enter the password once.

Not sure where the difference is, though.  I just checked and both are using the same version of bash (4.3.42).  I don't believe there are any settings in my .bash* files that is changing the behaviour...

(Perhaps you can try an Ubuntu 16.04 boot disk to confirm yourself what I'm seeing?)